# SQL Server Reporting : error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have SQL Server Reporting Services running on our live system. But when we trying to move same reports in to new database and new reporting server, then reports starting to fail with below error.

Highly appreciate if someone can help

SQL Server Reporting Services is showing this error

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
> Cannot read the next data row for the dataset 'DSProductJournal'. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

SQL query

```
SELECT     
    COMPANY, [Table], [Service Item Group],
    (CAST([Line No] AS char(10)) + [Order No_]) AS [Line No], 
    [Item No_], [Shelf No_], Quantity, [Serial No_], [Order No_], 
    Name, [Weight], Dimension, [Satus/OwnerShip], Condition,
    [E.T.A. / Rec’d Date], [Cost Amount (Actual)], [Cost Curr], 
    [Costing Completed], [Currency Code], [Exchange Rate Amount], 
    Special, [(Sales Price).(Unit Price)], [(Sales Price).(Minimum Quantity)], 
    [COSTED S/P CDN], [Location Code], [Profit _] AS [Profit],
    [Description Sales Price] AS [DescriptionSalesPrice],
    [Currency Code.Sales Price]
FROM
    dbo.V_ZItemLedgerEntryPurchLineUnionAll
WHERE  
    [Shelf No_] IN (@LOB)
ORDER BY
    [Service Item Group]
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory... you are trying to convert some string data to numeric data and its failing. You have to inspect your data and find and correct it. This shows why you should never store numeric data as a string. You could try using `try_cast` to identify the bad data (or filter it out).

Comment: Noticed that as soon as i remove "WHERE  [Shelf No_] in (@LOB)" query start to run. what  maybe the issue ?

Comment: Who knows :) the inner workings of SQL Server are mysterious and sometimes it obtains data in the early stages which it finds it no longer needs in the later stages. Doesn't change how you solve the problem.

Comment: Presumably `dbo.V_ZItemLedgerEntryPurchLineUnionAll` is a view and the error might reside within that definition. Your query also uses a variable so there is obviously more code involved than what you post.

Comment: Probably not @Smor , `IN (@LOB)` smells like SSRS parameter injection.

Comment: @Larnu Yes . something like that .. im now wondering

Comment: How can i convert IN (@LOB) parameter to nvarchar ? any help?

Comment: You don't, you define it as a string in SSRS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to update. this issue fixed by adding
WHERE  [Shelf No_] IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@LOB,','))

and adding =join(Parameters!LOB.Value,",") into the parameter